# Apply initial time offset to clock signal

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

If my clock signal toggles every 40ns but I want it to start toggling only after a specific delay, let's say 15ns, how can I do so using a Verilog testbench?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bit clock;
initial begin
    clock = 0;
    #15ns;
    forever #40ns clock = ~clock;
end
```